# Program goes infinite loop when semaphore is used (Deadlock)

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, deadlock, semaphore

The program is being executed correctly without semaphores, but when I use semaphores for sync, the program goes into an infinite loop (deadlock)!. I can't find out why this is happening. After being executed the program get inputs from the user and goes to an infinite loop; *This is seeking tutor problem.

Here are my functions with semaphores ->

```
void* CoOrdinator(void* arg)
{   
    
     sem_wait(&co);
    // sorting
    std temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < chair-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < chair-i-1; j++)
        {
            if (buffer[j].priority == buffer[j+1].priority)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if(buffer[j].priority>buffer[j+1].priority)
            {
                temp = buffer[j];
                buffer[j] = buffer[j+1];
                buffer[j+1] = temp;
            }
            
        }
        
    }

    

    // End Sorting

    printf("I'm a CoOrdinator\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < chair; i++)
    {
        printf("Student - %d -",buffer[i].id);
        printf("Priority - %d\n",buffer[i].priority);
    }
    
     sem_post(&tc);
    
}

// Teacher

void* Teacher(void* ox)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < teachers; i++)
    {
         sem_wait(&tc);
    
         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        
        tcObj[i] = buffer[out];
        
        out = (out+1)%chair;

        printf("Student - %d is in classroom. Priority: %d\n",tcObj[i].id,tcObj[i].priority);

         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
         sem_post(&st);
    }
    
    
    
    
    // // Studing with Teacher

    // for (int i = 0; i < teachers; i++)
    // {
    //  printf("Stuying with Teacher - %d", i);
    //  printf("Student - %d -",tcObj[i].id);
    //  printf("Priority - %d\n",tcObj[i].priority);
    // }

    
    
}

// Student
void* Student(void *px)
{
    
        // we have to use semaphore

        
        for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
        {
             sem_wait(&st);
            
             pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

             buffer[in] = stObj[i];
             in = (in+1)%chair;

             pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
             sem_post(&co);
            
    
            // if((int*)px == students)
            // {
            //  break;
            // }
        }

}
```

and the rest of the program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>

// Global Variables

int teachers, students, chair, help;

// Student Structure
typedef struct Student
{
    int id;
    int priority;

}std;

// Objects Array
std *stObj, *tcObj, *buffer;

// Buffer

int in = 0, out = 0;

// Semaphores

sem_t st, tc, co;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
```

main function

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    // Getting Inputs
    printf("Enter The Number Of Students: ");
    scanf("%d",&students);

    printf("Enter The Number Of Teachers: ");
    scanf("%d",&teachers);

    printf("Enter The Number Of Chair: ");
    scanf("%d",&chair);

    // Buffer Array

    buffer = (std*)malloc(chair * sizeof(std));
    stObj = (std*)malloc(students * sizeof(std));
    tcObj = (std*)malloc(students * sizeof(std));

    //Declaring Thread Variables
    pthread_t tc_thread[teachers], st_thread[students], co_thread;

    //Getting Priorities

    for(int i=0; i<students; i++)
    {
            stObj[i].id = i+1;
        printf("Enter The Priority of Student: ");
        scanf("%d",&stObj[i].priority);
    }


    // Mutex & Semaphores

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
        // sem_init(&empty,0,chair);
        // sem_init(&full,0,0);

    sem_init(&st, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&tc, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&co, 0, 1);
 
    // Creating Threads

    for (int i = 0; i < students; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&st_thread[i],NULL,Student,(void*)&stObj[i].id);
        pthread_join(st_thread[i],NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < teachers; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&tc_thread[i],NULL,Teacher,(void*)i);
        pthread_join(tc_thread[i],NULL);
    }

    pthread_create(&co_thread,NULL,CoOrdinator,NULL);
    pthread_join(co_thread,NULL);


    // Destroying Semaphores & Mutex

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
        sem_destroy(&st);
        sem_destroy(&tc);
    sem_destroy(&co);

    return 0;
}
```

is there any error?

Comment: It's suspicious to see semaphores used together with mutexes.  Not necessarily wrong, but usually one would use either semaphores OR a combination of mutexes and condition variables.

Comment: Both too much and too little information is provided.  Our usual expectation for debugging questions is that a [mre] be provided.  The code actually presented, however, contains a fair amount of material that is probably irrelevant, while omitting key details about how the semaphores and mutex are initialized and how the threads are started.

Comment: With that said, my guess would be that the issue has to do with the main thread's initialization and manipulation of the semaphores (which has not been presented).

Comment: I did not ask for the rest of your program.  I asked for a [mre] that is representative of your problem.  Follow the link for information about what that is and how to construct one.

Comment: 'the program goes into an infinite loop (deadlock)!' ????  Is the app blocked, or looping, ie is CPU use 0 or 100% ?

Answer (score 0):

The pthread_join is your problem.  Once the first loop of student has run, it has consumed the `st` semaphore and there is nothing to replenish it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < students; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&st_thread[i],NULL,Student,(void*)&stObj[i].id);
        pthread_join(st_thread[i],NULL);
    }
```

Remove the pthread_join from these loops; and after all threads have been created, add loops to join them.  So your main would look more like:

```
// Creating Threads
for (int i = 0; i < students; ++i)
{
    pthread_create(&st_thread[i],NULL,Student,(void*)&stObj[i].id);
}
for (int i = 0; i < teachers; ++i)
{
    pthread_create(&tc_thread[i],NULL,Teacher,(void*)i);
}
pthread_create(&co_thread,NULL,CoOrdinator,NULL);
pthread_join(co_thread,NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < students; ++i)
{
    pthread_join(st_thread[i],NULL);
}
for (int i = 0; i < teachers; ++i)
{
    pthread_join(tc_thread[i],NULL);
}
```

Also, unrelated to your immediate problem, this allocation:     `tcObj = (std*)malloc(students * sizeof(std));` should likely be `tcObj = malloc(teachers * sizeof(*tcObj));`  Note you had the wrong number; but also you should not cast malloc, and it is usually better to use sizeof(*var_you_are_assigning_malloc_to) since it is less fragile and self documenting.

Make these changes, and your program runs for a lot longer before hanging...